# Hook into Jetpacks Publicize without using a post type

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-jetpack

I have a plugin that allows users to power small amounts of data to thier sites. I don't use a custom post type for this but I would like to use Jetpack's publicize to publish to the sites connected social media.

Theres plenty in the jetpack documentation about adding it to a custom post type which doesn't apply in this case.

Is there an action I can call to publicize a message from in my plugin? e.g.

```
do_action('publicize_message', $message);
```

Comment: _I have a plugin that allows users to power small amounts of data to thier sites. I don't use a custom post type._ - Where are those data stored then? Using `post`, or `page`?

Comment: Jetpack sends the data to social media when you publish the post so it hooks in respective hook, where are you storing the data? And how you intend to publish it?

Comment: Data is stored in custom tables with relationships so adding new entries doesn't involve any of the normal WordPress hooks.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to let the user pick or type a message that then gets sent out through the selected services like a post.